# Serving media content from the closest client location

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing and application which allows users to upload and download media content: songs, videos...

My concern is that if my servers are located let's say in the Europe region for customer from America the application will feel very slow.
I was thinking to have something similar to Amazon S3 buckets created in different regions, then a client located in the Europe region will upload, download from the Europe region, a client from the Asia region will upload, download from the Asia region and so on. 
Then in some how find the way to synchronize all this buckets.

Is it possible?
Any better solution?

Thanks for your help

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) works with S3 but also with content stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a problem to consider using a [CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cdn/) to solve.  I'm familiar with Azure but I'd assume the competitors have similar offerings.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers multiple regions and zones to host your app:

**General overview:**
https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/

**Specific to cloud storage (which would probably host your content)**
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations

And finally the info for **Google CDN** is at https://cloud.google.com/cdn/